# stuck with code of php to add while loop condition

Tags: php, html, while-loop

i m trying to increment value 1 using while loop condition, i m developing quiz generation system, but stuck here and not found any solution, please help and tell what to do....

```
<?php
$ques2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE course='english' AND id='$id'");

$i = 1;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($ques2))
{
$i++;
$qech1=$rows['optiona'];
$qech2=$rows['optionb'];
$qech3=$rows['optionc'];
$qech4=$rows['optiond'];
$correct=$rows['correct'];
?>
<input type='radio' name='<?php echo $i; ?>' value='<?php echo $qech1; ?>'><?php echo $qech1."<br>"; ?><br>
<input type='radio' name='<?php echo $i; ?>' value='<?php echo $qech2; ?>'><?php echo $qech2."<br>"; ?><br>
<input type='radio' name='<?php echo $i; ?>' value='<?php echo $qech3; ?>'><?php echo $qech3."<br>"; ?><br>
<input type='radio' name='<?php echo $i; ?>' value='<?php echo $qech4; ?>'><?php echo $qech4."<br>"; ?><br>
<?php
}

?>
```

you seen above code, it is $i = 1; and then i echo $i as well in 4 fields of radio. it retrives around 3 questions from database and each question has 4 values, but all of the total of 12 values of 3 questions has same name that is 1, it is not increment using $i++ not sure why ?

here is out put

```
<span style='font-size:18px;font-weight:550px; '>english</span><br><input type='radio' name='1' value='kjk'>kjk<br><br>
<input type='radio' name='2' value='kjk'>kjk<br><br>
<input type='radio' name='2' value='jkj'>jkj<br><br>
<input type='radio' name='2' value='kjk'>kjk<br><br>
<span style='font-size:18px;font-weight:550px; '>adnan </span><br><input type='radio' name='1' value='jhwjksahajsh'>jhwjksahajsh<br><br>
<input type='radio' name='2' value='kjhjhjh'>kjhjhjh<br><br>
<input type='radio' name='2' value='kjhkjjh'>kjhkjjh<br><br>
<input type='radio' name='2' value='hjkjhj'>hjkjhj<br><br>
 <span style='font-size:18px;font-weight:550px; '>sdfsd</span><br><input type='radio' name='1' value='gfgf'>gfgf<br><br>
<input type='radio' name='2' value='gfg'>gfg<br><br>
<input type='radio' name='2' value='gfg'>gfg<br><br>
<input type='radio' name='2' value='gf'>gf<br><br>
```

Comment: Why do you have two braces $i++; } } ?

Comment: What does the second } belong to?

Comment: Where is the rest of the code in your `while()` loop? you have an extra `}` and your output has `<span style='font-size:18px;font-weight:550px; '>...</span>` but that is not in your code. You could be resetting `$i` to 1 somewhere in the missing code.

Comment: Try to put $i++; before $qech1=$rows['optiona'];

Comment: i just re update main main post code and added $i++ before $qech1=$rows['optiona']; now all name="2".... please suggest....

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Heredoc string to help you with this. I made a simple example that will output what you want in a simple way. Take a look:

```
<?php
$ques2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE course='english' AND id='$id'");

$i = 1;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($ques2))
{
$qech1=$rows['optiona'];
$qech2=$rows['optionb'];
$qech3=$rows['optionc'];
$qech4=$rows['optiond'];
$correct=$rows['correct'];
echo <<<HTML
    <input type='radio' name='$i' value='$qech1'>$qech1<br><br>
    <input type='radio' name='$i' value='$qech2'>$qech2<br><br>
    <input type='radio' name='$i' value='$qech3'>$qech3<br><br>
    <input type='radio' name='$i' value='$qech4'>$qech4<br><br>
HTML;

$i++;
}
```

Comment: But you don't want to group the radio buttons for each while loop?

Comment: i want to group, there are multiple questions, 1 question has 4 options as metioned in above code posted by you, it is fine, but is not doing increment, it stuck for all 5 to 6 questions to 1,1,1,1... not doing increment actually to 2,2,2,2 for next question and so on...

Comment: Sorry, but I tested the code and the output is correct. Take a look to the output here: http://codepad.org/fp2qFTlc

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't incrementing is because you are calling `$i` right after incrementing it.

```
while ... {
  $i++
   ...
   ..name="$i"...
}
```

Right now, it goes through the loop once and prints all names as 2. The next time all of them would be 3, etc.

What you want is more of a `foreach` loop.
I assigned basic values just for my testing purposes. I personally would eliminate assigning `$quech1 = $rows[optiona]`. You can just work with the array of `$rows` with the `foreach` loop.

```
<?php 
$ques2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE course='english' AND id='$id'");

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($ques2))
{
    $rows['optiona'] = "optiona";
    $rows['optionb'] = "optionb";
    $rows['optionc'] = "optionc";
    $rows['optiond'] = "optiond";
    $correct=$rows['correct'];
}
$i = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row){
    $i++;?>
    <input type='radio' name='<?php echo $i; ?>' value='<?php echo $row; ?>'><?php echo $row."<br>"; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

You'll see from my inspect element, that you are now getting incremented names:
[image: names incrementing]

However, if I'm not mistaken. Don't you generally want all of the names to be the same for a group of radio buttons? You'll want unique ID's. And then have all buttons that are to be grouped together with the same name. This makes it so only one button in that group can be selected. If that is what you're trying to accomplish, use the revised code:

```
<?php 
$ques2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE course='english' AND id='$id'");
$name = 1;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($ques2))
{
    $rows['optiona'] = "optiona";
    $rows['optionb'] = "optionb";
    $rows['optionc'] = "optionc";
    $rows['optiond'] = "optiond";
    $name++;
}
$i = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row){
    $i++;?>
    <input type='radio' id='<?php echo $i; ?>' name='<?php echo $name; ?>'value='<?php echo $row; ?>'><?php echo $row."<br>"; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Only change is that `$i` is being assigned to `id` now. And we'll declare a `$name` counter as well. We'll increment that in the `while` loop, so that it will only be incremented once for each set of button options. And then you use `$name` in the `name` attribute for the button.

That's what makes sense to me. But without more information, we don't really know exactly what you're trying to accomplish. :)

Comment: While this is true, this won't fix his problem. `$i` is 2 at the beginning, but the next loop should be 3, then 4, and so on.

Comment: yes. We are saying the same thing. And I threw this up while working on the correct answer.

Comment: issue is not that what is starting value, issue is that it wont do increment... it stuck in two........ it should go up like 2 then 3 then 4.............

Comment: Why the vote down? Does this not solve your problem? It gives you less lines of code, and increments the names like you wanted.

Comment: no vote down, it is up now sorry for that was mistaken.... Thank you for code, let me test...

Comment: Did that work? If so, go ahead and mark as answer. That way others will know it's resolved. :)